# Apache2 configuration for a static build of a SvelteKit project

Tags: apache, apache2, svelte, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project with two pages in the following structure:

```
+layout.js
+layout.svelte
+page.svelte
page-two
       |__+page.svelte
```

page-two is only accessible by typing out the URL as the root page doesn't link to it. When running the project locally using `vite dev`, appending `\page-two` to the URL loads the page correctly, however when deploying the project to an Apache2 server attempting to access `page-two` returns HTTP 404.

The following is my Apache2 configuration:

```
        ServerAdmin contact@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/project/build/

        // Logging
        // SSL
```

What configurations am I missing to access page-two from the URL?
I have tried adding the rules in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Abdelfattah-Radwan/a1b9a0951c0069715d133dac7c3e5cc0) to no avail.

Comment: Is `page-two` even included in the build if nothing links to it? You should see whether an HTML file for it exists in the first place.

Comment: @H.B. yes there is an HTML file in the output directory

Answer (score 1):

You've got options:

**A.** Enable SvelteKit's [trailingSlash](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#trailingslash) & Apache's [DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex)

```
// src/routes/+layout.js
export const trailingSlash = 'always';
```

and update the internal links to include the trailing slash.

**B.** Create a rewrite rule that looks for the `page-two.html` when the request is `/page-two`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: You should not need to set `DirectoryIndex`, the default matches when `trailingSlash` is set accordingly.

Comment: `mod_dir` is generally enabled and the `DirectoryIndex` defaults to `index.html` (which SvelteKit uses) but as Apache is modular I've included it for completeness.